# Cloning and adding the current repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code

I want to clone a project from github and use vscode or visual studio.
I clone the project locally with git clone but I can't push it to my repository. I'm probably doing something wrong.

What are the steps to add the entire cloned project (exactly as it is, with all branches, etc.) to an empty repository from my personal github?
Can you tell me, please, the variants both in vscode and in visual studio? I know you can use git commands.

Comment: full error message please.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your remote in the local git folder to your personal github repository:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git
```

Comment: And after this what should I do?

Comment: @Samsun then you can push into your new github repository

Comment: It doesn't woek, i don't know why. No errors

Comment: after running `git remote set-url...`,  if you run `git remote -v`, what is output?

Comment: this question has no debugging details and is almost certainly a duplicate. see the bottom of [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to above solution, you can try below.

```
git remote add <new-origin> <new-repository-URL>
git remote -v
git push <new-origin> --all
git push <new-origin> --tags
```